# How do I add an NSTextView to an NSScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

[This document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html). explains how to programmatically add an NSTextview (that can scroll) to a window. However, how do I programmatically add an NSTextView into an NSScrollView?

EDIT: Here's is the code that works with windows. I want to be able to programmatically insert an NSTextView into a NSScrollView I created with Interface Builder

```
-(IBAction)drawTextViews:(id)sender {

NSScrollView *scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc]

                            initWithFrame:[[theWindow contentView] frame]];

NSSize contentSize = [scrollview contentSize];


NSTextView *theTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0,

                                                           contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];

[theTextView setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)];

[theTextView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];

[theTextView setVerticallyResizable:YES];

[theTextView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];

[theTextView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];



[[theTextView textContainer]

 setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, FLT_MAX)];

[[theTextView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:YES];

[scrollview setDocumentView:theTextView];

[theWindow setContentView:scrollview];

[theWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

[theWindow makeFirstResponder:theTextView];*/


[[theTextView enclosingScrollView] setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];

[theTextView setHorizontallyResizable:YES];

[theTextView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];

[[theTextView textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];

[[theTextView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:NO];
```

Comment: Do you created NSScrollView programmatically?/

Comment: Also the link which you have pasted above does not help you??And also show your code. What did you try so far??

Comment: @HussainShabbir I updated the question to include the code. The scrollview for the NSTextField was created programmatically, but I want to insert the whole NSTextView into another NSScrollView I created with interface builder

Comment: As you have created the outlet of another scrollview. So just add the textview in your another scrollview like that 
[Anotherscrollview setDocumentView:theTextView];

Comment: @HussainShabbir yes, but that would set the whole scroll view as the NSTextView. I am just looking to have the NSTextView take up a section of the NSScrollView I created with Interface Builder

Comment: It will take always the whole scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments you can achieve an NSTextView within the scroll view by setting it as document view. If you want the textview only to take up a small part of the scroll view you have to construct that in another way. What is the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to know how to setup the text view as a part of the scrollview. So how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with programmatic creation of scrollable NSTextView. Based on my attempts I have created working example app: [How to create scrollable NSTextView programmatically?](https://github.com/stanislaw/Examples/tree/20160312-osx-scrollable-nstextview).

Here is relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat margin = 20;

    NSRect scrollViewRect = NSMakeRect(
        margin,
        margin,
        self.view.bounds.size.width - margin * 2,
        self.view.bounds.size.height - margin * 2
    );

    NSScrollView *scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewRect];
    scrollview.backgroundColor = [[NSColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
    scrollview.drawsBackground = YES;

    NSSize contentSize = [scrollview contentSize];

    scrollview.borderType = NSGrooveBorder;

    scrollview.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
    scrollview.hasHorizontalScroller = NO;

    scrollview.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;

    NSTextView *theTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollview.bounds];
    theTextView.drawsBackground = NO;

    theTextView.minSize = NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height);
    theTextView.maxSize = NSMakeSize(CGFLOAT_MAX, CGFLOAT_MAX);

    theTextView.verticallyResizable = YES;
    theTextView.horizontallyResizable = NO;

    theTextView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable;

    theTextView.textContainer.containerSize = NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    theTextView.textContainer.widthTracksTextView = YES;

    NSString *string = @"Once upon a time there was a little-known patent clerk in Bern who received a disappointing annual performance review in ’05";

    [theTextView insertText:string replacementRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];

    scrollview.documentView = theTextView;

    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
}
```